# How do you find all instances of ISBN number using Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I would really appreciate some assistance...

I'm trying to retrieve an ISBN number (13 digits) from pages, but the number set in so many different formats and that's why I can't retrieve all the different instances:

```
ISBN-13: 978 1 4310 0862 9
ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN9781431008629
ISBN 9-78-1431-008-629
ISBN: 9781431008629 more text of the number
isbn : 9781431008629
```

My output should be: `ISBN: 9781431008629`

```py
myISBN = re.findall("ISBN" + r'[\w\W]{1,17}',text)
myISBN = myISBN[0]
print (myISBN)
```

I appreciate your time

Comment: Can you indicate which ISBNs in the text are not "captured" by your regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split the problem to two steps. First to extract the potential ISBN and in the second step to check if the ISBN is correct (13 numbers):

```py
import re

text = """\
ISBN-13: 978 1 4310 0862 9
ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN9781431008629
ISBN 9-78-1431-008-629
ISBN: 9781431008629 more text of the number
isbn : 9781431008629"""

pat1 = re.compile(r"(?i)ISBN(?:-13)?\s*:?([ \d-]+)")
pat2 = re.compile(r"\d+")

for m in pat1.findall(text):
    numbers = "".join(pat2.findall(m))
    if len(numbers) == 13:
        print("ISBN:", numbers)
```

Prints:

```
ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN: 9781431008629
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
(?i)ISBN(?:-13)?\D*(\d(?:\W*\d){12})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cf5vUA/2). Then, remove all non-digits from Group 1 value.

*Regex details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier, same as `re.I`
- `ISBN` - an `ISBN` string
- `(?:-13)?` - an optional `-13` string
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digits
- `(\d(?:\W*\d){12})` - Group 1: a digit and then twelve occurrences of any zero or more non-word chars and then a digit.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mvtwqG):

```py
import re
texts = ['ISBN-13: 978 1 4310 0862 9',
    'ISBN: 9781431008629',
    'ISBN9781431008629',
    'ISBN 9-78-1431-008-629',
    'ISBN: 9781431008629 more text of the number',
    'isbn : 9781431008629']
rx = re.compile(r'ISBN(?:-13)?\D*(\d(?:\W*\d){12})', re.I)
for text in texts:
    m = rx.search(text)
    if m:
        print(text, '=> ISBN:', ''.join([d for d in m.group(1) if d.isdigit()]))
```

Output:

```
ISBN-13: 978 1 4310 0862 9 => ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN: 9781431008629 => ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN9781431008629 => ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN 9-78-1431-008-629 => ISBN: 9781431008629
ISBN: 9781431008629 more text of the number => ISBN: 9781431008629
isbn : 9781431008629 => ISBN: 9781431008629
```